# Positioning my logo inside the navigation bar using CSS

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I can't find some tutorials that will help me align the responsive navigation bar with the logo.

Sorry I'm just new in HTML & CSS and trying to create a website perhaps you can help me with me this by position it properly? and can you please provide also a link that will help me build a responsive website throughout my journey? thank you very much..

### Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Office the Naval Adjutant</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><img src="logoweb.png"></li>
    <li><a href='#'>ADMIN</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>MILITARY ASSISTANCE</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>RECORDS</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>PUBLICATION</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>GALLERY</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS:

```
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav{
    background-color: #233647;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 8px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
nav li a{
    color: white;
    padding: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
}
nav li a:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: #233647;
}
```

### It looks like this:

[image]

### But I wanted the output like this(I photoshoped it) which should be responsive:

[image]

Comment: Use Bootstrap(http://getbootstrap.com/). they provide the markup. you just need to put it and you can easily create responsive site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `#logo` and try, before that assign `#logo` to `image`. Reset height and width according to your logo size.

```
#logo{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px; 
    left:10px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
<li>
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" id="logo"></li>
<li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap for making your website responsive, they have defined all classes you just have to use them.
[bootstrap link with navbar as you need]

[1]http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/
check it out..!

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out :D